# How to create a virtual environment to check network application

Tags: network-programming, virtualization

I want to create a client server application to test socket created and threads are running between client and server.
I want to check this for internet application.
But being on local machine. I cannot check.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a virtual machine on your real machine and a bridge-mode network connection between the two.  Then run the server on one and the client on the other.

However, you will not get a good picture of how well it responds under heavily loaded network conditions.  For that you truly need a private network with a phantom load generator.

VirtualBox, VirtualPC, and vmware can do this.  You might get better/more responses on superuser.com.

Comment: Thankyou for answer, I have VmWare installed on my machine. and network adapters are bridged but how would i be able to test it for internet based service

Comment: Do you mean you wish to observe the connections between an existing client and an internet based server?  Use a program like WireShark to monitor the communications between your local machine and the server.  If I still don't understand your question then you will need to explain your situation in more detail.